# My dropdown is not working - having trouble with the JS

Tags: javascript

I have a simple dropdown menu but I am having trouble with the JS.

Every time I click on "li" the dropdown menu (Which is inside the "li") appears which is great but the issue is when I want to dropdown to disappear I click on the "li" again but ".slideToggle()" does not appear to be turning it off.

However if I double click the "li" really fast it gets rid of the dropdown as intended but obviously this is very bad UX.

Please can someone check my code?

```
  $('.dropdown-li').click(function(){

     $('.navigation-dropdown').removeClass('enabled');

    $(this).toggleClass('enabled');

    $('.dropdown-li').addClass('enabled');

    if ($(this).hasClass('enabled')) {
        $('.navigation-dropdown').stop().hide();
        $('.navigation-dropdown', this).slideToggle();
    } else{
        $('.navigation-dropdown', this).slideToggle();   
    }   

    return false;  

});
```

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please?

Comment: `slideToggle();` after `.hide()` will show the item. Have one or another, not both.

Comment: Sorry but this is all the JS thats being used, I will try what you suggested though, thanks.

Comment: Im sorry Nivas but your suggestion didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely different jQuery from what you're currently using, but it worked for me in a previous project:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".showhide").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(1);
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
});
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle example. I hope this is what you're looking for! http://jsfiddle.net/4zdjn262/

Comment: Thanks IronFlare, I will keep trying with code for now but if I still cannot get it to work I will go with your suggestion :)

Comment: IronFlare, I took a quick look at your JSFiddle and I was wondering how you would close the other "ul" when you click on another "li". So when you click on "Expand 1" and then immediately click on "Expand 2" how you would close "Expand 1"?

Comment: I modified the code to collapse all other lists when a list is clicked on. http://jsfiddle.net/4zdjn262/2/ Also, to make it a little more pleasant to the eye, I changed the slideToggle time from 1 (instant) to 400. If you don't care about the animation or you don't want it, you can replace `slideToggle(400)` with `slideToggle(1)` and `.slideUp(400)` with `.hide()`.

Comment: IronFlare you're absolute lifesaver!! I have implemented this into my site and it works fine. You dont know how long this has taken me to get working :L I really appreciate this :) Do you have Skype?